# Most common docblock for Delphi and/or FreePascal code

Tags: delphi, comments, freepascal, code-documentation, docblocks

I'm quite familiar with PHP dockblocks since it's been my job for the last 15+ years.

```
/**
  * Description
  *
  * @tag bla bla
  * @tag more bla bla
  */
```

What I'm trying to understand is if there is a standard like that for Delphi and/or FreePascal.

From my analysis on an awful lot of code I never seen any, but I could be dead wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Delphi documentation tools

Using the XMLDoc tool for API documentation and HelpInsight with Delphi 2005
  [http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32770](https://web.archive.org/web/20220815212311/https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32770)

XML Documentation in Delphi 2006
  http://tondrej.blogspot.com/2006/03/xml-documentation-in-delphi-2006.html

DelphiCodeToDoc
  http://dephicodetodoc.sourceforge.net/

Doc-O-Matic
  http://www.doc-o-matic.com/examplesourcecode.html

PasDoc
  http://pasdoc.sipsolutions.net/

Pascal Browser
  http://www.peganza.com/

Doxygen
  http://www.doxygen.nl/

Pas2Dox
  http://sourceforge.net/projects/pas2dox/

JADD - Just Another DelphiDoc
  http://delphidoc.sourceforge.net/

### Stackoverflow discussion

Is there a Delphi code documentor that supports current Delphi syntax?
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673248/is-there-a-delphi-code-documentor-that-supports-current-delphi-syntax

Code documentation for delphi similar to javadoc or c# xml doc
  [Code documentation for delphi similar to javadoc or c# xml doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236047/code-documentation-for-delphi-similar-to-javadoc-or-c-xml-doc)

Documenting Delphi
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336/documenting-delphi

Answer (score 7):

Latest Delphis support parsing of XML documentation. They also use this information in hints (for example if you move the mouse cursor over a method name).

I'm using this template for method documentation:

```
///<summary></summary>
///<param name=''></param>
///<returns></returns>
///<exception cref=""></exception>
///<since>2009-04-15</since>
```

Comment: @gabr: Could you include the link for the complete syntax on that please?

Comment: @gabr: could you at least give use your own memory's neurons mapping ? ;)

Comment: I'm only using the tags mentioned above plus <author> and <remarks> in unit header.

Answer (score 1):

[It looks like doxygen has a tool](http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html) which can be used in conjunction to [document Pascal and Delphi code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pas2dox/). Maybe that will help you.

Comment: +1 I use doxygen and pas2dox in all my commercial Delphi / Free Pascal libraries, commenting in JavaDoc style works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

On a project I'm currently working on, we're using [DelphiCodeToDoc](http://dephicodetodoc.sourceforge.net/), which works reasonably well. Its syntax looks like this:

```
type
  {* This is an example class }
  TMyClass = class
  private
  protected
  public
    {* Does some twiddling with AParam, and returns the result as String
       @param AParam Input value
       @return AParam incremented by 2, as String
       @throws Exception 'Boo' if it's full moon }
    function MyFunction(AParam: Integer): String;
  end;
```

Comment: I know this is just an example and I'm nit-picking, but a procedure does not return values right? ;)

Comment: Lol :D Yeah, of course you're completely right. Corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer docs outside of the source (it always gets messy), and use the excellent fpdoc that comes with FPC. (FPC's own docs are written in it).

Answer (score 0):

There are several standards, usually depending on the documentation tool being used. We use PasDoc, so we adhere mostly to its format http://pasdoc.sipsolutions.net/ which is based on JavaDoc.

Alternatively, there is XMLDoc as gabr pointed out and there are quite a few other tools, most having similar syntax with subtle differences.